# Arduino Christmas Lights

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, led

Ok so my question is regarding the hardware of a string of lights. You may have seen the project before where people use arduino to program a string of lights, but I have a really long string of 50, and I'd like to cut it.

[image: Arduino LED String of Lights]

So the issue is that I'm not sure which wires are which because most lights use Red (power), Blue (ground), Green (clock), and Yellow(data) whereas my string of leds uses Red, White, and two blue, meaning my white wire and one of my blue ones represents the Green and Yellow from the diagrams. I went ahead and cut the string in half - but there were only 3 wires in the middle! One of the blue wires ends after the first led, so each led has only a red, white, and blue wire between them. I tried linking the lights as I did before I cut it, but the lights didn't follow the code. They just lit up in random colors, switching after every second or so. Which wires are which? Can someone tell me how to make sure that the data is going through?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they are not RGB leds, but WS2812. This kind of leds are powered by a 5V supply, are individually addressable, and are controlled through a serial link.

Almost every project I saw used the fastled library: http://fastled.io/

And.. Be happy. With your led strip you will get more light effects than with the other type..

Answer (score 0):

> my string of leds uses Red, White, and two blue

As @frarugi87 said, you probably have some adressable leds (WS28xx)

Red is Vcc

BOTH blue wires are GND.

White is the data pin. These are adressable leds so you only need one data pin to control all the leds.